# Subclipse: Compare with usage

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I did a svn checkout from the repository and as well svn update using tortoise svn. I want to know what were the changes happened in the code. How can I do that using subclipse. Help me out.

Comment: Changes between what? Do you mean you want to see the changes that happened between the initial checkout and the update? If so, doing `svn log -v` will show the commit messages. Those should (ideally) summarise the changes that were committed for each revision.
EDIT: In tortoiseSVN you'd choose 'show log' from the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project/folder/file and choose Team > Show History.  That will show the changes.  You can right click on specific revisions in the history to compare the current code with the code at that version, or to compare that version with previous version etc.

Context matters.  The History option will show the history based on the object you selected when you take the option.  So if you want the history of all changes, you select the project or a parent folder of the code you care about.  If you just want one file, then select that file.